# How do I calculate SHA-256 hash of a list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sha256

I am trying to replicate JS method:

JS code:

```
const toHexCopy = (buffer) => {
            return [...new Uint8Array (buffer)]
                .map (b => b.toString (16).padStart (2, "0"))
                .join ("");
};

ar = new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2]);
hash = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', ar)
console.log(toHexCopy(hash))

// returns 039058c6f2c0cb492c533b0a4d14ef77cc0f78abccced5287d84a1a2011cfb81
```

How do I replicate it in Python?

Comment: Do you want to hash a `list` or a sequence of bytes? Those are very different questions.

Comment: @Brian, basically I want to get same output as in JS.  I have a list in Python, if needed, I can covert it to bytes.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from hashlib import sha256
print(sha256(bytes([1, 2, 3])).hexdigest())
```